# Mapper for POJOs in Java

Tags: java, reflection, mapping, dozer

I am writing a mapper to map fields of 2 different POJOs in java. I have used Dozer mapper for simple mapping but in this case, I have a slightly complex strategy when it comes to set the value to the destination object. The getter is simple, but instead it setting it directly, I want to do some processing on the value.

My question is, can I use dozer mapper for my cause? 
In case if its not possible, is it ok (from performance point of view) to use reflection to implement my own mapper (this is because I have defined the mapping in an xml file and dont want to hardcode it in the mapper class)?

```
<mapping>
  <field>
   <!-- source -->
   <field-a name="cat">
   <!-- destination -->
   <field-b" name="dog">
  </field>
</mapping>
```

Relevant to this xml, I want the following:

```
Source c;
Destination d;
d.setDog(someProcessing(c.getPsMessage()));
```

Note down the extra processing (`someProcessing`) after getting the value and before setting it to the destination object.

Comment: can you please put an example of namings?

Comment: Hard to grok what you want, include some relevant snippet(s) of code

Comment: I have added the code snippet to be a bit more clear in what I am trying to achieve. Also update the question a bit.

Answer (score 3):

You can set your [own `getters`-`setters` methods with Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/custommethods.html#). You can even map attributes with different type and name!:

Example:

```
<field>
    <a>yourField</a>
    <b set-method="nameOfYourFieldSetter(java.lang.String)">
        nameOfYourFieldInOtherClass
    </b>
</field>
```

---

> Note down the extra processing (someProcessing) after getting the value and before setting it to the destination object.

You're overcomplicating things, use KISS principle:

```
Source c;
Destination d;
// String, Integer or what someProcessing returns!
String name = someProcessing(c.getPsMessage()); 
d.setDog(name);
```

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question a bit. I need to do some processing before I could assign the field to the destination object.

Comment: @ObaidMaroof please check my edit, I think you can simplify your code and use it as it... ;)